# Code compiles despite having arithmatic operations in `case` statement. Aren't those not allowed there in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I was just practicing C and I found a program that has arithmetic operators used in `case` statement. But I've learned that arithmetic operations cannot be used in such place.
Then how is this program working?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ch = 'a' + 'b';

    switch (ch) {
        case 'a':
        case 'b':
            printf("You entered b \n");

        case 'A':
            printf("a as in ashar \n");

        case 'b'+'a':
            printf("You entered a and b \n");
    }

    return (0);
}
```

According to me the variable `ch` will store ASCII values of character `'a'` + `'b'`, i.e. `ch = 97 + 98` that becomes `ch = 195;`
The `switch(ch)` will match to case with 195, i.e. `case 'a' + 'b'`.

But the problem is how can we use arithmetic operators in `case` against rules of the C language?

Comment: Which rules? If it evaluates to a constant value then it's fine.

Comment: You cannot use arithmetic operations with variables on __case__ statement. but 'a' & 'b' are both constant and be treated as 195, as your guess, at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

They are allowed no problem as long as they are *integer constant expression*.

From C99 standard [§ 6.8.4.2](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A290%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D) point 3:

> The expression of each `case` label shall be an integer constant expression (...)

And [§ 6.6](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A212%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D) point 6 describes it as:

> An *integer constant  expression* shall have integer type and  shall  only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer  constants, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only
> convert  arithmetic  types to integer types, except as part of an  operand to the `sizeof` operator.

And [§ 6.6](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A212%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D) point 2 says:

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.

In [§ 6.2.5](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A88%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D) point 14 we read:

> The type `char`, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the  enumerated types are collectively called integer types. The integer and real floating types are collectively called real types.

And also in [§ 6.4.4.4](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A140%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D) point 2:

> An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed in single-quotes, as in `'x'`. (...)

All elements of `'a' + 'b'` expression are known at compile time.
Values written in single quotes are integers, so characters are also just integers.
Compiler can evaluate the expression and just replace it with the resulting `195`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the language that prevents using the `+` operator in a `case`.

The requirement is that the case value be an **integer constant expression**.  Such an expression cannot contain an assignment, increment, decrement, function call, or comma operator, but other operators are allowed as long as each subexpression is a constant.

Section 6.8.4.2p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describes the requirements for a `case`:

> The expression of each `case` label shall be an integer constant expression and no two of
> the `case` constant expressions in the same `switch` statement shall have the same value
> after  conversion

Section 6.6p6 describes an integer constant expression:

> An *integer constant  expression* shall  have  integer  type  and
> shall  only  have  operands that are integer constants, enumeration
> constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions  whose  results
> are  integer  constants, `_Alignof` expressions,  and  floating
> constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in
> an integer constant expression  shall  only  convert  arithmetic
> types  to  integer  types,  except  as  part  of  an operand to the
> `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

And section 6.6p3 describes the constraints on operators in a constant expression:

> Constant  expressions  shall  not  contain  assignment,  increment,  decrement,  function-call,
> or  comma  operators,  except  when  they are  contained  within  a  subexpression  that  is  not
> evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard (C99)

> The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant expression and no two of the case constant expressions in the same switch statement shall have the same value after conversion. There may be at most one default label in a switch statement. (Any enclosed switch statement may have a default label or case constant expressions with values that duplicate case constant expressions in the enclosing switch statement.)

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.

Expression `'b'+'a'` will be translated at compile time and is therefore a constant expression, which, as you have noted, evaluates to 195.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `'b' + 'a'` is a sum of constants and will probably be replaced by it's resultant constant at compile time.